# Unique image name not generated when uploading picture from phone to firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am making a web app using firebase and react.js. The app works fine when a user posts an image using a computer, because an image has a filename already that the computer or the user of that computer gave it. However, when someone access my app via mobile phone, they can still upload a images, but upon refresh the images all disappeared except for the last one because they are all being given a default name since photos in a camera roll aren't named, therefore in firebase storage this default name given to all phone images is being replaced with the most recent one, losing the rest.

Here is my function where I am trying to generate a unique ID despite where the uploaded image comes from, to avoid any collision in firebase storage:

```
const handleUpload = () => {
    //const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${image.name}`);
    const randomId = doc(collection(db, "temp")).id;
    //image.name = randomId;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${randomId}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);

    uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
            //Progress function ... (shows the load bar)
            const progress = Math.round(
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            );
            setProgress(progress);
        },
        (error) => {
            //Error Function...
            console.log(error);
            alert(error.message);
        },
        async () => {
            //complete function
                const url = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
                const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "posts"), {
                    imageURL: url, 
                    caption: caption, 
                    username: username, 
                    timestamp: serverTimestamp()
                });

                console.log("THE APP HAS POSTED");
                setProgress(0);
                setCaption('');
                setImage(null);
                setUrl('');
            }
        )
            

    }
```

As you can see I am generating a unique ID with `const randomId = doc(collection(db, "temp")).id;`. This works when I print to the console on my computer. It assigns this unique ID to any image uploaded via a computer.

However it does not generate and assign a unique ID for images uploaded from a phone which is causing the collision and only the most recent phone image to be saved in the database.

Does anyone have an idea on how to generate a unique ID to stop collison despite what kind of device the image is coming from?

Comment: It might be a good idea to keep updating existing question (which apparently is deleted) instead of reposting it. That at least has some context to the issue and anyone else won't have to start over by suggesting the ways to fix this which were already suggested..

Comment: I think i've narrowed down the issue to this question, I thought it wrapped everything up nicely.

Comment: I tried running the app from your Github repository and ran the app on a phone, it still uploaded a new image. Have you tried using any other device.

Comment: It does upload a new image, however if you upload multiple from a phone, then refresh the app, only the most recent one is reloaded on the screen.